# Animated image does not have transparent background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-animated, react-native-stylesheet

In my react-native application, I want to render a spinning logo as the right header for a screen.

```
<Stack.Screen
      name="About"
      component={About}
      options={{headerRight: () => <SpinnerIcon />}}
    />
```

And the spinner component returns an `Animated.Image`

```
<Animated.Image
        source={require('../img/reactLogoTwo.png')}
        style={[{width: 50, height: 50}, {transform: [{rotate}]}]}
      />
```

The image I have saved in `img` folder has a transparent background ([downloaded from here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngfind.com%2Fmpng%2Fhmibwoi_react-logo-png-white-transparent-png%2F&psig=AOvVaw1AjrL7zQbuvETF2Z8-ck2n&ust=1604494990881000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCLiGweG35uwCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ)) but the animated image rendered with a white background.

[image]

Notes: adding `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` does not work.

Comment: simply do `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` in image style

Comment: @Harrison Edited the question, that does not work

Answer (score 1):

I made this example as Snack: https://snack.expo.io/@zvona/animated-transparent-image

According to it, there's no conflict between transparent PNG's and `Animated.Image`. Are you using *react-native-animated* library?

Secondarily, setting style `backgroundColor: 'transparent'` might help, but I don't see what could cause that peculiar behavior.